# how to pass the input type in jQuery to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a basic bootstrap form, and I want to pass the input type through to php via ajax. I can get the input name & value with `serializeArray()`.

**How would I extend the output from `serializeArray` to also include the input 'type'?**

---

Some more info... Here's my current form...

```
<form id="second_example_form" class="form-horizontal core_form_submission" action="#" method="post" data-callback="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/form-second-example.callback.php'; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input id="email" class="form-control" required type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the ajax calling js...

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = form.serializeArray();

    $.post('ajax/forms.ajax.php', {
            data: data
    }, function(r) {
        var json = JSON.parse(r);
    }
});
```

`var data = form.serializeArray();` works great to pass the name and value... but doesn't include input type.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you might have to get each value seperatly. eg $('#email').val()

Comment: I can get the value with serializeArray(), it's the input 'type' I'm struggling with specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a mixture of the other answers, to create a new array from scratch.

```
// Collect all of the fields in the form, their values and types
function gather_form_fields(form)
{

    var output = {};
    form.find(':input').each(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr('type'),
            name = $(this).attr('name'),
            val = $(this).val();

        // If it's a select or other element without a 'type', return the element
        if (type == null) {
            type = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
        }

        // remove the submit button
        if (type == 'submit') {
            return true;
        }

        output[name] = {
            type: type,
            name: name,
            value: val
        };
    });

    return output;
}
```

This then produces an object with the type, name and value e.g.

```
data = {
    first_name: {
        name: "first_name",
        type: "text",
        value: "joe"
    },
    email: {
        name: "email",
        type: "email",
        value: "jbloggs@test.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialize does not provide that, you would have to construct name value of all the types and pass that to your server.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
  $('input, select', this).each(function() {
    formData.push({
      name: $(this).attr('name') + '_type',
      value: $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase()
    });
  });
  console.log(formData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="second_example_form" class="form-horizontal core_form_submission" action="#" method="post" data-callback="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/form-second-example.callback.php'; ?>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input id="email" class="form-control" required type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me close, I've posted my own answer along these lines but with a bit more flexibility on the input type and the type as it's own element in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can send the type within the value or the name.
In your php you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate the type from the value/name. Here's how to send it within the value.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var fields = e.serializeArray();

    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        var item = e.find(':input').eq(i);
        var fieldType = item.attr("type") === null ? item.prop("tagName") : item.attr("type");
        fieldType = fieldType === null ? item.prop("tagName") : fieldType;
        data.push({"name": fields[i].name, "value": fieldType + "|" + fields[i].value })
    }

    $.post('ajax/forms.ajax.php', {
            data: data
    }, function(r) {
        var json = JSON.parse(r);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this normal `serializeArray` function I did quick fix and  sharing  code with two alternative.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//Make sure name and id will be same id=email_email name = email_email
   var fields = $( "#second_example_form" ).serializeArray();
   fields = fields.map(function(val){
    val.type =  $( "#"+val.name ).attr("type");
    return val;
    });
    console.log(fields);
//Change only name and add type with name seprated by _ like this name = name_type    
   var fields = $( "#second_example_form" ).serializeArray();
   fields = fields.map(function(val){
    val.type =  val.name.split("_")[1]
    return val;
    });
    console.log(fields);
 });
```

```css
body, select {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  form {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <form id="second_example_form" class="form-horizontal core_form_submission" action="#" method="post" data-callback="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/form-second-example.callback.php'; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input id="email_email" class="form-control" required type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email_email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 messages"></div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```